# PHP/MySQL Check if not updated because same values

Tags: php, mysqli, insert

I've been researching this issue for two days now and nothing I found works for me. Here is the case:
A user sets some data, if there is a row for that `user_id(Primary Key)` the row is updated, if there is not the row is inserted. So far so good, but when the user sets the same values, it is not updated and the insert query is executed, which shows an error because there is already a row for that `user_id`.
So how can I detect that the row is not updated because it has the same values and not execute the insert?

Currently my code is:

```
UPDATE %s SET %s WHERE `user_id`=%d
if ($this->db->affected_rows() <= 0) {
    INSERT...
}
```

And since the values are the same and `mysqli_affected_rows` returns `0` I get:

```
Duplicate entry 'xxxxx' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

From what I've read `INSERT IGNORE` is not recommended, because it doesn't show errors and I need to know if there are such. `INSERT ON DUPLICATED KEY` is very slow and I don't want to use it. So what are my options here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY is NOT slow and is what you actually need

Comment: Thanks. I will convert the INSERT in an INSERT UPDATE.